# About roboflown's assist function

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, yolo, yolov5, roboflow

Annotated in roboflow and trained in YOLOv5(https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5).
I annotated the model in roboflow and trained it in YOLOv5.
After that, I want to do label assist using the custom model I learned, but I can't do it. What should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the dataset version you generated to train in YOLOv5 to use Roboflow Train: https://docs.roboflow.com/train - once your Training Job is complete, you’ll have access to Model-Assisted Labeling (Label Assist): https://docs.roboflow.com/annotate/model-assisted-labeling

Your workspace comes with 3 free Roboflow Train credits by default.

Comment: I created a custom dataset from version 1 to 5. At that point, label assist was usable. However, when I deleted version 1, it is no longer usable. Versions 1 to 5 are the same class, just different number of sheets.

Comment: The label assist checkpoints are not available if you delete a version, as that would delete the record of the model weights being used for label assist. If there was a need for a storage upgrade, and this is a business project, you can contact the sales team: https://roboflow.com/sales. If it is a personal or research project (not business use), and you need sponsorship for the increase, file this form: https://roboflow.com/community

Comment: Can't label assist be trained in python without training in Roboflow?